# Matching latent fingerprints

Tags: probability-theory

Question:

Imagine that fingerprint evidence is found at the scene of a crime. The probability that it matches a person by chance is 1 in 5,000. The evidence is compared to a database of 30,000 people’s fingerprints.  Find the probability it matches at least 1 person in the database by chance alone.

Here’s what I did:

So, let the sample space be the exact number of matches between the latent fingerprint and a sample from the database.
$$\Omega = {0,1,2,...,n}$$

The subsets can be described as combinations of matches and non matches. However, I will partition the sample space into two subsets.  The set containing all the sets with a least one match and the set containing no matches.  The compliment of at least one is none.  Find the probability of 0 matches and the probability of at least one match will be 1 - Prob(o).

Let A be the event that at least one fingerprint is a match.

However, the latent fingerprint is compared to all 30,000 members of the database.  It can be assumed that each trail is independent because the question states that a match is based on chance alone.

Therefore, $$\ P(A) = 1 - (\frac{4999}{5000})^{30000} = 0.9975$$

So, based on chance alone it’s not likely one will not find a match.

Next question, If the guilty person is in the database, find the expected number of people in the database who match the fingerprint evidence.

Since at least 1 in every 5000 is a possible match and there are 30000 people in the database.  I would expect that on average 6 people would be a possible match.

Is my reasoning and approach to solve this problem correct?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.